# Fiddler doesn't capture SOAP Action

Tags: soap, fiddler

How do we find the SOAP action in fiddler:-

I captured the text view of the request. It doesn't show the request SOAP action:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header><a:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><a:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><a:Username>LP_DEALIO@SERVICES</a:Username><a:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Abc.1234</a:Password></a:UsernameToken></a:Security></s:Header><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Get__CompIntfc__LP_PC_PROJECT_GEN xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas/M676402.V1"><BUSINESS_UNIT>US001</BUSINESS_UNIT><PROJECT_ID>LM202017</PROJECT_ID></Get__CompIntfc__LP_PC_PROJECT_GEN></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SOAP Action is found in the Headers Section in Fiddler. Something like this:-

```
POST /PSIGW/PeopleSoftServiceListeningConnector/PSFT_EP/CI_LP_PC_PROJECT_GEN.1.wsdl HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPo+YluAuf3g9BhNp2nGC57WUAAAAA60+5s/MerUGZDfyhBXBAgPyLh3Vk3hZMrWvRTb0KntcACQAA
SOAPAction: "CI_LP_PC_PROJECT_GEN_UP.V1"
Host: psf92extigw.am.jll.com
Content-Length: 1039
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```